# How to post a web link through http post in android

Tags: android

I want to just post a weblink in my app and i tried the following code.

```
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");
     HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

but it does not work.
Help me

Comment: What are you posting and you need to set the post data and the content-type header accordingly.

Comment: I am just posting a web link like http://www.yoursite.com/script.php how to set the content-type header

Comment: When you post data to a url, then the server looks at the stream as it expects incoming data from the client and based on the content type header it knows how to parse the incoming data. So if you posting json data then you set the Content-Type header to application/json.                                  httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient
                .execute(httpPostRequest);
```

Use this code......i hope its useful to you.

please add permission in androidmanifest file

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Nope,the program gets crashed.Is there any other way to post a weblink in android

Comment: Check if your application have permission for internet

Comment: I am getting error only in  HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

Comment: My main thing is that i want to post a link so that i get a response.Is there any other methods

Comment: Guys,Thanks for your response i did the job with PostDataAsyncTask method

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("\http://www.yoursite.com/script.php\");
     HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```